# clip-path подсказки с прозрачным фоном содержимого

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, clip-path

Я создал clip-path подсказки  с границей (очень важно).  Теперь я пытаюсь сделать фон содержимого прозрачным.

Вот мое текущее решение:

```css
.background {
  background: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/birch-forest-sunny-day-green-woods-summer-spring-landscape-43067305.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}

.clip-svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.clip-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #639;
  background-color: rebeccaPurple;
  clip-path: url("#speechebubble-clip");
}

.clip {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.clip {
  clip-path: url("#speechebubble-clip");
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="clip-wrap">
    <div class="clip">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<svg class="clip-svg">
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="speechebubble-clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
  <path width="100%" height="100%" transform="scale(0.0045, 0.00385)" id="clip-mask" d="M34.1983772,243.81581 C35.2123618,243.81581 36.0373744,244.643759 36.0373744,245.661353 L36.0373744,260 L63.450348,244.064408 C63.7301493,243.901754 64.0488773,243.81581 64.3720879,243.81581 L233,243.81581 L233,2 L2,2 L2,243.81581 L34.1983772,243.81581 Z" />
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

Можно ли сделать белый блок содержимого прозрачным?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [clip-path speech bubble with transparent content background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50256772/7394871) от участника  [@R-J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319724/r-j).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/50256772/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Если вы открыты для другой идеи, я бы подумал об использовании нескольких фонов и клипов для достижения этой цели:

```css
body {
  background: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/birch-forest-sunny-day-green-woods-summer-spring-landscape-43067305.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}

.bubble {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin:20px auto;
  position: relative;
  border:3px solid purple;
  background:
  linear-gradient(purple,purple) 0 100%/40px 20px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(purple,purple) 100% 100%/100px 20px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,purple 50.5%) 40px 100%/40px 20px no-repeat;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% calc(100% - 19px), 80px calc(100% - 19px), 40px 100%, 40px calc(100% - 19px), 0% calc(100% - 19px));
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% calc(100% - 19px), 80px calc(100% - 19px), 40px 100%, 40px calc(100% - 19px), 0% calc(100% - 19px));
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble">
 some text
</div>
```

А вот еще одна идея использования псевдоэлемента, чтобы избежать clip-path:

```css
body {
  background: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/birch-forest-sunny-day-green-woods-summer-spring-landscape-43067305.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}

.bubble {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin:20px auto 60px;
  position: relative;
  border:3px solid purple;
  border-bottom:none;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to right,purple 20px,transparent 20px,transparent 80px,purple 0)0 100%/100% 2px  no-repeat;
  position:relative;
}
.bubble:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-38px;
  left:17px;
  width:62px;
  height:40px;
  border-left:3px solid purple;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent calc(50% - 2px),purple calc(50% - 2px),purple 50%,transparent 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble">
 some text
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50257240/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>